# Algorithm to generate an evenly distributed random permutation

Tags: algorithm, distribution, permutation

I have a set of N questions, each one categorized as one of R subjects. I'm trying to generate some random permutation of the questions for a quiz.

How would I generate a random permutation of the set of questions such that no two consecutive questions have the same subject? It does not need to be perfect; I just don't want to bore people with five of the same type of question in a row.

Additionally, if such an ordering is not possible (as in, 18 of A and 2 of B), could the algorithm find an "evenly distributed" permutation? (in this case, something reasonably like 6As, B, 7As, B, 5As)

Alternatively, since I'm delivering the questions sequentially, could I each time randomly select a remaining question of a different subject without the chance of forcing some repeats at the end?

I've looked around randomly on Google for a while and can't seem to find anything that fits this case. Other than randomly generating permutations until you find one that works, which is slow, ugly and stupid.

Comment: The reason why you can't find anything "random" that fits your case, is because your constraints actually make it **not random**. You want it to be balanced, not random.

Comment: ... what exactly does "closed as off topic" mean, and why does it apply to this question? ?_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

1. Group your questions into R groups according to their subject.
2. Shuffle each group separately
3. Interleave the groups depending on their relative size, so that they are evenly spaced.

This is simple and fits your requirements. A bit of 'randomness' is lost because the interleaving is always the same (i.e. question from subject 1, then from subject 2, then from subject 3, and start with subject 1 again).

This could be improved by randomizing the order in which you pick groups for each iteration.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that works exactly as requested! Agreed, a lot of randomness is lost, but I suppose that randomness isn't exactly the most important thing in this setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the previously used subject from the list of candidate subjects.

For example, in Java, suppose you have 10 subjects:

```
   Subject previous = listSubjects.get( 0 );
   while( true ){
      listCandidateSubjects.remove( previous );
      int xSelection = Random.nextInt( 10 );
      Subject current = listCandidateSubjects.get( xSelection );
      listCandidateSubjects.add( previous );
      // generate question for current subject here
      // when have enough questions break
      previous = current;
   }
```

Comment: Well, since I'm starting with a fixed set of subjects, I might end up without any possible questions to use once I get to the end. For example, starting with AAABB, I might get BABA... then what? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @user2449745 If you read the code you will see that the previously removed subject gets added back in after the selection. The code I have listed does exactly what your question said you wanted to do: avoid the possibility that no two succeeding questions come from the same subject.

Comment: But see my example: if I have 3 of subject A and 2 of subject B, and I happen to start with B... then it'll go B, A, B, A, then we'd have an error because there's no more Bs to choose from.

Comment: @user2449745 Look, your question stated that YOU DID NOT WANT QUESTIONS FROM TWO SUBJECTS IN A ROW. Thats what my algorithm delivers. If you want to start creating all kinds of exceptions and corner cases you need to specify what those are exactly.